# Python xlsx to csv without change date to interger

Tags: python, csv, datetime, xlsx

I need to write a python script to change from .xlsx file to .csv file:
my code :

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Att1FF5.tmp')
    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in sh.row_values(rownum)])

    your_csv_file.close()

csv_from_excel()
```

However , all the date format was changing to integer . for example :

4/13/2018 --> 43203

So is there anyway i can alter my code to keep the date format. My date format is believed to be MM/DD/YYYY

thanks.

Comment: Excel formats values for you. Are you sure that the raw XLSX data actually has dates?

Comment: Why not use `pandas` instead of `csv`, and parse as dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [xlrd document](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html), I guess you have to do the conversion yourself, since there is no date type stored in excel.

As the document says, `Excel for Windows stores dates by default as the number of days (or fraction thereof) since 1899-12-31T00:00:00`. The date of `43203` can be calculated like this:

```
import datetime, xlrd

xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_tuple(43203, 0)  # returns (2018, 4, 13, 0, 0, 0)
xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(43203, 0)  # returns datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 13, 0, 0)
```