# Xlsxwriter - Dynamically change the formatting based on column label

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to define the formatting that needs to be applied to each column of an excel spreadsheet based on the column name.

For example, if column name is '**count**' then '**number_format**' needs to be used. If column name is '**sale_date**' then '**date_format**' needs to be used.

```
number_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0', 'font_size': 12})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss', 'font_size': 12})
```

Using the above two formats in the respective columns as shown below:

```
worksheet1.write('A1', 'count', number_format)
worksheet1.write('B1', 'sale_date', date_format)
```

Could I make this dynamic based on the column name instead of defining format by column label. Thanks

**Update:**

Loop that displays the header column in the excel spreadsheet

```
for data in title:
    worksheet.write(row, col, data, number_format)
    col += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Comment**: `date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})`, shows the date column as unix number rather than a proper date.
>   Sample value shown is : `42668` instead of displaying `"24-10-16"`.

This is default behavior defined by Windows Excel.
Read [Excel for Windows stores dates by default as the number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879795/7414759)
Documentation: [XlsxWriter Working with Dates and Time](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html)

---

> **Comment**:  ...that I could use the appropriate format based on column name (namely count, sale_date)

You can use `worksheet.set_column()` to set a Style for a whole Column.
Documentation: [XlsxWriter worksheet.set_column()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html)

**Precondition**: The Order of the Columns Name/Style must be in **sync** with your table.
E.g. `count == 'A'`, `sale_date == 'B'` and so on...

```
from collections import OrderedDict

_styles = OrderedDict([('count',number_format), ('sale_date', date_format), ('total', number_format), ('text', string_format)])

for col, key in enumerate(_styles):
    A1_notation = '{c}:{c}'.format(c=chr(col + 65))
    worksheet.set_column(A1_notation, None, _styles[key])
    print("worksheet.set_column('{}', None, {})".format(A1_notation, _styles[key]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, number_format)
> worksheet.set_column('B:B', None, date_format)
> worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, number_format)
> worksheet.set_column('D:D', None, string_format)
> ```

For subsequent writes you don't need to assign a `style`, e.g. use

```
worksheet.write('A1', 123)
```

will default to `A:A number_format`

---

> **Question**: Could I make this dynamic based on the column name

You are not using *"column name"*, it's called **Cell A1 Notation**.
Setup a mapping `dict`, for example:

```
style_map = {'A': number_format, 'B':date_format}
```

> **Usage**:
>   **Note**: This will only work with *single* letter, from `A` to `Z`

```
def write(A1_notation, value):
    worksheet1.write(A1_notation, value, style_map[A1_notation[0]])
```

---

For Row-column notation `(0, 0)`:

```
style_map = {'0': number_format, '1':date_format}
```

> **Usage**:

```
def write(row, col, value):
    worksheet1.write(row, col, value, style_map[col])

from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

def write(A1_notation, value):
    worksheet1.write(A1_notation, value, style_map[xl_cell_to_rowcol(A1_notation)[1]])
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Just to make sure I got this right, we are first creating a dictionary of 2 pairs (one for number_format and the other for date_format).. We then use "worksheet1.write(row, col, value, style_map[col])" to define the formatting by column.. Is my understanding right, thanks..

Comment: *"2 pairs (one for number_format and the other for date_format)"*: Not **only** how many unique *styles*, there must be a `dict` key for **every** Column.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Just one more query I had was I have included the "for loop" that displays the column names in the excel spreadsheet as part of my initial post. Could you please advice how i could have this modified such that I could use the appropriate format based on column name (namely count, sale_date).. Thanks..

Comment: thanks for your update.. One problem I am having is I trying to convert date columns in this format "date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})" .. This however shows the date column as unix number rather than a proper date.Sample value shown is : 42668 instead of displaying "24-10-16"

Comment: sorry for not accepting your answer earlier.. I was trying to check if you could help me with this other problem as well.. I was trying to see how we could display the actual date and not just the unix date format.